# If I've answered a question that got closed as duplicate differently from the answers in the linked-to question, should I re-post there?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Here's the situation. I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24013649/175157) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24013458/175157), but the question got closed as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/283297/175157). I agree that it is indeed a duplicate.

However, I feel that my answer handles cases that have not been covered in the answers of the older question. So the question is, should I post my answer in the older question as well? It seemed logical, so I did it, but it feels weird, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Well, why not? If it answers the other question too...

Comment: Have you considered flagging your answer for moderator attention and asking for it to be merged into the canonical question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you are adding info that isn't already covered in the dupe you should repost the answer there (or edit/comment an existing answer as appropriate) in order to benefit the community

Comment: OK, I just wanted to be sure I'm not supposed to merge them somehow :)

Comment: **Merging duplicates** is the future of information handling ... but SO is not there yet